# In Thymeleaf image is not displaying

Tags: html, thymeleaf

**See the Image Section commented below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ORDER CONFIRMATION</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>www.HobbyShop.com</h3>

    <h3>Thank You for your purchase, <span th:utext="${purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName()}"></span></h3>

    <h3>Order summary</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Product Image</th>
                <th width="50%">Product Detail</th>
                <th width="30%"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="orderItem : ${purchase.getOrderItems()}">

                <!-- Image section -->

                <td>
                     <p> <span th:utext="${orderItem.imageUrl}"></span>  </p>

                    <img  th:src="@{orderItem.imageUrl}" width="150px"/>
                </td>

                <!-- end of image section -->

                <td>

                    <p> <span th:utext="${ orderItem.name }"></span>  </p>
                    <p>Unit Price: <span th:utext="${ orderItem.unitPrice}"></span>  </p>
                    <p>Quantity: <span th:utext="${ orderItem.quantity}"></span>  </p>

                </td>

                <td>

                    <p>Subtotal: <span th:utext="${ orderItem.quantity * orderItem.unitPrice }"></span> </p>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>


    <h5>Total Quantity: <span th:utext="${purchase.getOrder().getTotalQuantity()}"></span></h5>
    <h5>Total Price: <span th:utext="${purchase.getOrder().getTotalPrice()}"></span></h5>



    <h3>Order Details</h3>

    <h5>Your order will ship to:</h5>


    <h5 style="margin: 0" > <span th:utext="${purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName()}"></span>  <span th:utext="${purchase.getCustomer().getLastName()}" ></span> </h5>
    <h5 style="margin: 0"> <span th:utext="${purchase.getShippingAddress().getStreet()}" ></span> </h5>
    <h5 style="margin: 0"> <span th:utext="${purchase.getShippingAddress().getCity()}"></span>, <span th:utext="${purchase.getShippingAddress().getState()}"></span>, <span th:utext="${purchase.getShippingAddress().getZipCode()}" ></span> </h5>
    <h5 style="margin: 0"> <span th:utext="${purchase.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}" ></span> </h5>


    <h5>Your order Tracking Number: <span th:utext="${purchaseResponse.getOrderTrackingNumber()}"></span> </h5>





</body>
</html>
```

In `<p> <span th:utext="${orderItem.imageUrl}"></span>  </p>` I can see the image url which is AWS s3 object url where image is stored.

Image URL: `https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-157391262832.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Books/Rafi12534@Gmail.com/ArtOfComputerProgramming.jpg`

But In  `<img  th:src="@{orderItem.imageUrl}" width="150px"/>` image url is not found.
If i hardcode the image url like this:
 `<img  th:src="@{https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-157391262832.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Books/Rafi12534@Gmail.com/ArtOfComputerProgramming.jpg}" width="150px"/>`
it works.

To me it seems like in img tag we are not getting the img url. but in th:utext image url is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for using a `${...}` expression inside of a `@{...}` expression is:

```
 <img th:src="@{${orderItem.imageUrl}}" width="150px" />
```

(See the [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#using-expressions-in-urls) documentation.)  In this case, however, there really is no reason to use the standard URL syntax at all.  You can simply use the variable directly.

```
<img th:src="${orderItem.imageUrl}" width="150px" />
```

The reason `@{orderItem.imageUrl}` fails is because Thymeleaf is treating `orderItem.imageUrl` as a string, and not a variable (equivalent to `@{'orderItem.imageUrl'}` which will resolve to `<img src="/context/orderItem.imageUrl" width="150px" />` -- you can see this by simply viewing the source and noticing that your variable wasn't parsed).